# Can the sheath of nonmetallic cable be removed prior to entering electrical metallic tubing (EMT)?

Tags: electrical, conduit

Can 2 romex cables be stripped before entering an EMT to allow more conductors in a 1/2" EMT? How would you transition from Romex to individual conductors going in or out of the EMT? Or is that allowed?

Answer (score 1):

The wires inside Romex are THHN type, which is okay for EMT, but you cannot use a bare copper wire inside EMT.  I would transition from Romex cable to EMT with a metal box.  Bond the bare copper wires to the box with a grounding pigtail, and add a insulated green THHN wire to continue the ground through the EMT.

Comment: I don't believe you can -- my understanding was that the wires have to be individually labeled and I didn't think the wires inside Romex were individually labeled? I could be wrong though. There are also limitations to the number of wires you can have inside a 1/2" EMT as well.

Comment: Apparently the size of a romex when in an EMT is calculated rather strangely. The width of the flat Romex represents the diameter and the volume is calculated as if it is a complete circle which dramatically reduces the amount of Romex permitted in the EMT. Far more THHN would be permitted. At least that's the info I've found.  @Edwin  Thanks, very helpful. Jacob S I appreciate the info. Thanks